# Parse any HTML form with Go

Tags: forms, go

I want to parse a form which looks like this:

```html
<form method="post">

  <input type="text" name="foo" value="bar"/>
  <input type="text" name="blue" value="baz"/>

</form>
```

I could parse this particular form with the help of [net/html](//golang.org/x/net/html), but maybe there is already a way to parse every HTML form into a struct which I can use for `request.PostForm()`?

For example, it would be quite difficult to parse a select-multiple input.

There is a Python library which does this. In the unit test of this library, you see examples: *[test_html_form_to_dict.py](https://github.com/guettli/html_form_to_dict/blob/main/html_form_to_dict/tests/test_html_form_to_dict.py)*

Comment: Could you show some examples of "difficult" cases, and your desired results in those cases?

Comment: I use https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery when I want to parse HTML to a struct. You basically use jQuery selector as tags.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco I updated the question and added a link to examples.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do it:

```
package html

import (
   "encoding/xml"
   "io"
   "net/url"
)

type form struct {
   Input []struct {
      Name string `xml:"name,attr"`
      Value string `xml:"value,attr"`
   } `xml:"input"`
}

func newForm(r io.Reader) (*form, error) {
   f := new(form)
   err := xml.NewDecoder(r).Decode(f)
   if err != nil {
      return nil, err
   }
   return f, nil
}

func (f form) values() url.Values {
   val := make(url.Values)
   for _, input := range f.Input {
      val.Add(input.Name, input.Value)
   }
   return val
}
```

Comment: HTML is not XML, and you would miss a lot of valid HTML by using a XML parser.